# Dojo InlineEditBox wouldn't initialize

Tags: javascript, dojo

Trying to use InlineEditBox as it is described in the [tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/InlineEditBox.html).

The code hasn't been changed:

```
require(["dijit/InlineEditBox", "dijit/form/Textarea", "dojo/domReady!"], function(InlineEditBox, Textarea){
    var eb = new InlineEditBox({
        editor: Textarea,
        autoSave: false
    }, "ieb").startup();
});
```

For some reason, I've got an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
```

Running `debugger` show that InlineEditBox never initializes. E.g.
`new Button()` creates a widget as shown in console, while `new InlineEditBox()` returns null.

Comment: do you have a placeholder like `<div id="ieb"> some text </div>` inside your body element?

Comment: @frank Yes, the placeholder is there. Even if I remove placeholder name from new InlineEditBox() it still throws the same error. I've already tried to debug this in multiple way, just don't understand why it doesn't see this specific widget - InlineEditBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/68kxLc7k/) and it works as expected.

Can you show us your HTML code.?

```
<body class="claro">
<div id="ieb">
    When you click on this div you'll be able to edit it (in plain text).
    The editor's size will initially match the size of the (original) text, but will expand/contract as you type.
</div>

<script>
require(["dijit/InlineEditBox", "dijit/form/Textarea", "dojo/domReady!"], function(InlineEditBox, Textarea){
    var eb = new InlineEditBox({
        editor: Textarea,
        autoSave: false
    }, "ieb").startup();
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is part of big project and I cannot post it here. Looks like the problem is unique to the project.. something affects it.

Comment: What I've figured out: dijit.InlineEditBox returns null. E.g. dijit.form.Button - returns the object code.